# Python: Imported csv not being split into proper columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, delimiter

I am importing a csv file into python using pandas but the data frame is only in one column. I copied and pasted data from the comma-separated format from [The Player Standing Field table at this link (second one)](http://baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2016-standard-fielding.shtml) into an excel file and saved it as a csv (originally as ms-dos, then both as normal and utf-8 per recommendation by AllthingsGo42). But it only returned a single column data frame.

Examples of what I tried:

```
dataset=pd.read('MLB2016PlayerStats2.csv')

dataset=pd.read('MLB2016PlayerStats2.csv', delimiter=',')

dataset=pd.read_csv('MLB2016PlayerStats2.csv',encoding='ISO-8859-9', 
delimiter=',')
```

The each line of code above all returned:

Rk,Name,Age,Tm,Lg,G,GS,CG,Inn,Ch,PO,A,E,DP,Fld%,Rtot,Rtot/yr,Rdrs,Rdrs/yr,RF/9,RF/G,Pos Summary
1,Fernando Abad\abadfe01,30,TOT,AL,57,0,0,46.2...
2,Jose Abreu\abreujo02,29,CHW,AL,152,152,150,1...
3,A.J. Achter\achteaj01,27,LAA,AL,27,0,0,37.2,...
4,Dustin Ackley\ackledu01,28,NYY,AL,23,16,10,1...
5,Cristhian Adames\adamecr01,24,COL,NL,69,43,3...

Also tried:

```
dataset=pd.read_csv('MLB2016PlayerStats2.csv',encoding='ISO-8859-9', 
delimiter=',',quoting=3)
```

Which returned:

```
"Rk                        Name  Age   Tm  Lg    G   GS   CG     Inn    Ch  
\
0  "1      Fernando Abad\abadfe01   30  TOT  AL   57    0    0    46.2     4   

1  "2        Jose Abreu\abreujo02   29  CHW  AL  152  152  150  1355.2  1337   

2  "3       A.J. Achter\achteaj01   27  LAA  AL   27    0    0    37.2     6   

3  "4     Dustin Ackley\ackledu01   28  NYY  AL   23   16   10   140.1    97   

4  "5  Cristhian Adames\adamecr01   24  COL  NL   69   43   38   415.0   212   

   E   DP   Fld%  Rtot  Rtot/yr  Rdrs  Rdrs/yr  RF/9  RF/G  \
0      ...        0    1  1.000   NaN      NaN   NaN      NaN  0.77  0.07   
1      ...       10  131  0.993  -2.0     -2.0  -5.0     -4.0  8.81  8.73   
2      ...        0    0  1.000   NaN      NaN   0.0      0.0  1.43  0.22   
3      ...        0    8  1.000   1.0      9.0   3.0     27.0  6.22  4.22   
4      ...        6   24  0.972  -4.0    -12.0   1.0      3.0  4.47  2.99   

Pos Summary"  
0            P"  
1           1B"  
2            P"  
3     1B-OF-2B"  
4     SS-2B-3B"
```

Below is what the data looks like in notepad++

```
"Rk,Name,Age,Tm,Lg,G,GS,CG,Inn,Ch,PO,A,E,DP,Fld%,Rtot,Rtot/yr,Rdrs,Rdrs/yr,RF/9,RF/G,Pos Summary"
"1,Fernando Abad\abadfe01,30,TOT,AL,57,0,0,46.2,4,0,4,0,1,1.000,,,,,0.77,0.07,P"
"2,Jose Abreu\abreujo02,29,CHW,AL,152,152,150,1355.2,1337,1243,84,10,131,.993,-2,-2,-5,-4,8.81,8.73,1B"
"3,A.J. Achter\achteaj01,27,LAA,AL,27,0,0,37.2,6,2,4,0,0,1.000,,,0,0,1.43,0.22,P"
"4,Dustin Ackley\ackledu01,28,NYY,AL,23,16,10,140.1,97,89,8,0,8,1.000,1,9,3,27,6.22,4.22,1B-OF-2B"
"5,Cristhian Adames\adamecr01,24,COL,NL,69,43,38,415.0,212,68,138,6,24,.972,-4,-12,1,3,4.47,2.99,SS-2B-3B"
"6,Austin Adams\adamsau01,29,CLE,AL,19,0,0,18.1,1,0,0,1,0,.000,,,0,0,0.00,0.00,P"
```

Sorry for the confusion with my question before. I hope this edit will clear things up. Thank you to those that answered thus far.

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not work"? Did you get an error message?

Comment: @user2314737 It would import, but the delimiter would not separate the data unless I used the quoting=3. That split the data but returned what I described to the first and last columns.

Comment: Please provide sample code snippet, sample data snippet and full traceback (if any). If you do not get a traceback please elaborate about the difference between the desired data format and the data you get currently.

Comment: `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('"'))`?

Comment: Is the csv from a PC that might have a different locale? It might not be UTF-8 and even though it looks like a comma, it could actually be something else from a different character set. I see this happen with the " from german PCs. I would open the text file in Notepad ++ and double check the encoding.

Comment: @JD22 Welcome! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information about how to ask a good question fitting  to this site!

Comment: Please open the `.csv` in a text editor and copy-paste the first few lines into your question.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thanks but it returned an attribute error

Comment: @Robᵩ added the text to the bottom of question

Comment: @zerox1212 No, the data was changed to comma separated on the web then I copied that info into an excel file and saved it as a csv

Comment: I suspect that you copied the table entirely into the first column of your excel spreadsheet. Then, when you saved the file as CSV, it saved it as a single-column CSV, hence the `"`s around each line. Do either of these: 1) don't use Excel. Instead, copy-paste the CSV from the web into Notepad++. Save the CSV file from Notepad++, or 2) don't copy-paste. Instead, save the .xls from the web. Open it in Excel and Save-As CSV from there.

Comment: I did the first option you suggested and it worked! Thanks! I tried the second one before but it only does 500 rows at a time. Thanks again Rob and everyone that helped! Sorry again for the confusing question post...

Comment: Thank you all again for the feedback! I gave you all a shoutout on twitter (@JohnnyData22), Linkedin, and my website (jddata22.com)

Answer (score 0):

Running it quickly myself, I was able to get what I am understanding is the desired output.

[image]

My only thought is that there i s no need to call out a delimiter for a csv, because a csv is a comma separated variable file, but that should not matter. I am thinking that there is something incorrect with your actual data file and I would go and make sure it is saved correctly. I would echo previous comments and make sure that the csv is a UTF-8, and not an MS-DOS or Macintosh (both options when saving in excel)

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you AllThingsGo42. I tried saving it as a normal csv and UTF-8 and importing again, but unfortunately still got the same results....thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call for a delimiter for a csv. You only have to change the separator from ";" to ",". For this you can open your csv file with notepad and change them with the replace tool.